# Photo of me holding my passport

Tags: passports

I applied for a job outside the country. The HR Department of the company I am applying is asking me to send a photo of me holding my passport close to myself.

Is it legal or should I still continue the hiring process?

Comment: Are they asking just to see the cover of the passport, or asking to see an interior page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about traveling. It's about laws / workplace.

Comment: @user68959 I voted to close since this is not a travel question. In any case you should be aware that in some countries making copies of an ID is ilegal. Before doing anything else make sure the company really exists and that you are actually contacting someone from the company and not a fake HR department say it belongs to some known company.

Comment: Sounds like they are trying confirm you, your name, id, etc all exist.

Comment: Following up on nsn's comment: a question like this need country/nationality information.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan they are asking the first two pages of the my passport. Thanks.

Comment: Which country is that about?

Comment: This question should be migrated to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ . There are similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds unusual for sure, I work closely with HR and have never come across this.

What is totally normal and will often be requested is a photocopy of the main page  of your passport and, if relevant, the visa for the country in question. This is a thoroughly reasonable request, many countries laws ask for this even to confirm that somebody has a right to work.

What it seems to me they are doing here...Is confirming that you are who you say you are. Maybe they've had problems with fake passports before; people photoshopping passports knowing that it is unreasonable and often illegal for the employer to ask to inspect your real passport.

By having a copy of your passport and a picture of you with the passport, with the passport open from an unusual angle, they can try to confirm that yes, this is a real passport.

Sounds pretty odd and unprofessional to me. You should make 100% sure this is a valid job first- it is not unknown for scammers to ask for ID and such proof pictures which they then use for use in future scams (pretending to be you...).

But assuming this is a totally legitimate company and all checks out then asking for a scan of your passport is normal. Asking for this extra picture on top of that...weird and quirky but its not like you're losing anything by following through.